# Use an object attribute to create an array with it

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi guys i want to do something "simple" but not for me, I have this array

```
[
  { x: 'bmw', vehicule_type: car, y: 1 },
  { x: 'mercedes', vehicule_type: car, y: 2 },
  { x: 'airbus', vehicule_type: plane, y: 1 }
]
```

And i want to transform it to this thing

```
[
  car : [{ x: 'bmw',  y: 1 },  { x: 'mercedes', y: 1 }]
  plane: [{ x: 'airbus',  y: 1 }]
]
```

I cant find a way to do it, i saw that i could use "reducer()" but for the rest i'm lost

Comment: No need for `reduce`. Use a normal loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const myTransform = arr => (
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, {vehicule_type, ...rest}) => (
      (acc[vehicule_type] ??= []).push({...rest}),
      acc
    ),
    {}
  )
);

/* EXPLANATION of the code

// method to transform the array
const myTransform = arr => (
  arr.reduce(         // iterate using ".reduce()" with "acc" as accumulator
    // destructure the iterator to acces "vehicule_type"
    (acc, {vehicule_type, ...rest}) => (
      // if "acc" doesn't have "vehicule_type", set it as empty array
      // and then, push "rest" (ie, x, y, other props, if any) into the array
      (acc[vehicule_type] ??= []).push({...rest}),
      // implicit return of "acc"
      acc
    ),
    {}      // initialize "acc" as an empty object
  )
);

*/

const dataArr = [
  { x: 'bmw', vehicule_type: 'car', y: 1 },
  { x: 'mercedes', vehicule_type: 'car', y: 2 },
  { x: 'airbus', vehicule_type: 'plane', y: 1 }
];

console.log(myTransform(dataArr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

**EDIT**

As noted by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) in a comment below, an alternative using `for` loop is also possible. This may look something as shown below:

```js
const myTransform = arr => {
  const res = {};
  for (const {vehicule_type, ...rest} of dataArr) {
    (res[vehicule_type] ??= []).push({...rest});
  };
  return res;
};

/* EXPLANATION
// alternative method to transform the array
const myTransform = arr => {
  // set up result "res" as an empty object "{}"
  const res = {};
  // iterate over elts of "dataArr"
  // destructure the iterator to directly access "vehicule_type"
  for (const {vehicule_type, ...rest} of dataArr) {
    // if "vehicule_type" not already in "res", 
    // then, set it with a value of empty array
    // push the remaining props "...rest" into the array
    (res[vehicule_type] ??= []).push({...rest});
  };
  // return the result
  return res;
};
*/

const dataArr = [
  { x: 'bmw', vehicule_type: 'car', y: 1 },
  { x: 'mercedes', vehicule_type: 'car', y: 2 },
  { x: 'airbus', vehicule_type: 'plane', y: 1 }
];

console.log(myTransform(dataArr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: It would be cleaner (and require less explanation :P) to use a normal loop instead of `reduce` where the accumulator is just passed through

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts @Bergi. Appreciate your time & effort. My answer is, partially, an attempt to utilize different features of javascript (to reinforce my own learning, by repetition). If another n00b like me reads the answer & tries to read + understand any particular aspect (such as reduce, or ??=, or implicit return, etc) of javascript, I would consider that as a win for me. :-). Hope it is not against any policies in stackoverflow, though.

Comment: @Bergi, edited the answer with one using `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the data by `vehicle_type` using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const 
  data = [
    { x: "bmw", vehicle_type: "car", y: 1 },
    { x: "mercedes", vehicle_type: "car", y: 2 },
    { x: "airbus", vehicle_type: "plane", y: 1 },
  ],
  result = data.reduce(
    (r, { vehicle_type: t, ...o }) => ((r[t] ??= []).push(o), r),
    {}
  );

console.log(result);
```

If you're finding it difficult to understand the above solution, refer to this more descriptive version:

```js
const 
  data = [
    { x: "bmw", vehicle_type: "car", y: 1 },
    { x: "mercedes", vehicle_type: "car", y: 2 },
    { x: "airbus", vehicle_type: "plane", y: 1 },
  ],
  result = data.reduce((r, { vehicle_type: t, ...o }) => {
    if (!r[t]) {
      r[t] = [];
    }
    r[t].push(o);
    return r;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```

**Relevant documentations:**

- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)
- [Comma operator (,)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: Would be cleaner using a normal loop instead of `reduce` where the accumulator is just passed through

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the best way to do this; probably not, but this is what I came up with..

```js
let array = [{
    x: 'bmw',
    vehicle_type: "car",
    y: 1
  },
  {
    x: 'mercedes',
    vehicle_type: "car",
    y: 2
  },
  {
    x: 'airbus',
    vehicle_type: 'plane',
    y: 1
  },
  {
    x: 'mercedes',
    vehicle_type: "car",
    y: 2
  }
]

function sortByType(array) {
  const vehicles = {};
  for (let object of array) {
    let vehicle = {},
      type = undefined;
    for (let property in object) {
      if (type === undefined) type = object["vehicle_type"];
      if (vehicles[type] === undefined) vehicles[type] = [];
      if (property === "vehicle_type") continue;

      vehicle[property] = object[property];
    }
    vehicles[type].push(vehicle);
  }
  return vehicles
}

const vehicles = sortByType(array)
console.log(vehicles)
```

Comment: Any idea why it tells me that object in (object of array) is not defined ?

Comment: Is the array you're passing in identical to the one I'm passing in as a function argument? compare the two arrays to see if there are any discrepancies

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Code:

```js
const data = [{ x: 'bmw', vehicle_type: 'car', y: 1 },{ x: 'mercedes', vehicle_type: 'car', y: 2 },{ x: 'airbus', vehicle_type: 'plane', y: 1 },]

const result = data.reduce(
  (a, { vehicle_type: v, ...c }) => ((a[v] = [...(a[v] || []), c]), a), 
  {}
)

console.log(result)
```